# writting a test suite in Postman

Tags: json, postman

I am trying to run a test suit in post man by json file upload, and executing test cases by .xl file upload.

my test.json file look like below,

```
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "af0ea50c-4264-41a6-ac2c-bcacbf966394",
        "name": "CCAPI TEST",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "API TEST",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "id": "c195d434-6bb6-4c00-ae21-3d71552b86f0",
                        "exec": [
                            "let expected_response = pm.variables.get(\"expected_response\");\r",
                            "\r",
                            "console.log(\"expected_response:\"+expected_response + \" ->responseBody:\"+responseBody);\r",
                            "pm.test(\"Body matches string\", function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(responseBody).to.include(expected_response);\r",
                            "}); "
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [
                    "Accept":"application/json",
                    "Content-Type":"application/json"
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "raw",
                    "raw": ""
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "{{ip_port}}/CCAPI/subscription",
                    "host": [
                        "{{ip_port}}"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "CCAPI",
                        "subscription"
                    ],

                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ]
}
```

In postman I am passing below data in body,

```
{
   "name":"abc",
   "number":"919876567876",
    "value":"ENABLE"
}
```

POSTMAN RESPONSE:

```
{
"description":"successfully added",
"status":"success"
}
```

I want to pass the same to the json file, I am not getting where should I add this,

for result once the test is created after uploading the file, I click on run , there I will upload the .xl file, from there It has to check for the output of the api is matching or not

.xl file contents :

> name  number  value expected_response
>
> abc   988988999 ENABLE {"description":"successfully
>   added","status":"success"}

I am not getting where to add the body of the json REQ in the .json file
If anyone tried running test suite in postman tool who knows this reply